# JConsole: Java Monitoring and Management Console

Tags: java, jvm, jdk

> JConsole

Olá, li que esta ferramenta faz o monitoramento dos processos da JVM.
Porém, ao executar a ferramenta aparece este formulário (vide imagem). 
Quanto a estes parâmetros, o que eles significam? 
Não lembro de configura-los no momento da instalação do Java.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava acessando o aplicativo de monitoramento de outro diretório **(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\lib)**, da pasta **lib**, porém é só de monitoramento remoto.
acessei o **jconsole** da pasta **bin**, **(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin)** e consegui monitorar minha aplicação local perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

é só acessar o .exe da pasta:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin